# Customize Laravel 8 Passport methods

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, laravel-passport

The login validation I use is not Laravel's default. How do I customize Passport methods?

The following code I use to validate with web middleware.

```
$username = $request->username;
$password = strtoupper(md5($request->password));

$system = env("CODE_SYSTEM", 12);

$sql = "SELECT user.validate( '$system' , '$username', '$password')";
$stmt = DB::select(DB::raw($sql));
$result = $stmt[0]->validation;

if ($result == "ok") {
    $user = new User();
    $id = DB::table('users')->select('id')
        ->where('username' , $username)->first();
    $user = User::find($id->id);

    return $user;
}
```

Comment: Don't! Just don't!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To customize you need add the `validateForPassportPasswordGrant()` at User method, example:

```php
public function validateForPassportPasswordGrant($password)
{
    $password = strtoupper(md5($request->password));
    $system = env("CODE_SYSTEM", 12);

    $sql = "SELECT user.validate( '$system' , '$this->username', '$password')";

    $stmt = DB::select(DB::raw($sql));
    $result = $stmt[0]->validation;

    if ($result == "ok") {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

If you need to change the user column name where the passport search username:

```php
public function findForPassport($username)
{
    return $this->where('the_username_column', $username)->first();
}
```